# auth_basic within location block doesn't work when return is specified?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

i thought this would work but for some reason it skips the auth_basic and always returns 200. Same happens if i swap 200 for a 301 redirect.

If i comment out the return statement it works ok. Ideally i want just an `/auth` endpoint that once authenticated it will 301 redirect to another path.

```
 location /auth {
     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
     auth_basic "Secret";

     return 200 'hello';
  }
```

Am i missing something ?

many thanks

fLo

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`return`-directives are executed before most other directives. To solve your problem you need to split this into two locations:

```
location /auth {
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  auth_basic "Secret";
  try_files DUMMY @return200;
}

location @return200 {
  return 200 'hello';
}
```

The `try_files`-directive is evaluated after `auth_basic`. The second location is evaluated only as a result of `try_files`.

Comment: OK thanks, confirmed working. I tried to find some documentation that confirms this but wasn't able to find it on nginx site or else where. If anyone has some where that confirm this is expected behaviour or maybe a bug ? thanks.

Comment: I have never found official documentation about this. The source code confirms this behavior and there this presentation: http://de.slideshare.net/joshzhu/nginx-internals , see slide 37 and following. The `return`-directive belongs to the rewrite module. Also this article: http://www.nginxguts.com/2011/01/phases/

Comment: This doesn't work when you also want to set a cookie. add_header Set-Cookie "foo=bar" before try_files does nothing.

Comment: @Rihad The add_header directive needs to come in the named location (before the return), then the cookie is written. This is because the request is actually handled in this location, i.e. the content and headers are created there.