# NGINX skipping authentication on location

Tags: nginx

We want our entire server to be protected from anonymous access except for one endpoint `/public`. However we are seeing the location `/ping` accessed anonymously with status 200.

Why?

Surely we do not need to put authentication directives on each location block?

```
server {

  location /ping {
    return 200 'OK'; # Should not be available anonymously!
  }

  location = /public {
    auth_basic off;
    return 200 'OK'; # Should be available anonymously
  }

  # Users must authenticate in general
  satisfy any;
  auth_basic "Authentication";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/my/.htpasswd;


}
```

According to the docs this should work:

> Alternatively, you you can limit access to the whole website with basic authentication but still make some website areas public. In this case, specify the off parameter of the auth_basic directive that cancels inheritance from upper configuration levels:

```
server {
    ...
    auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;

    location /public/ {
        auth_basic off;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `return 200 'OK';` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40463578/4862445). For anything that's not part of the rewrite module - it should work ok.

Comment: Maybe the location blocks should follow the authorization config - not precede ?

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith I've posted a working answer - feel free to answer and I'll mark yours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Richard Smith for the tip - we need a workaround as `return` is executed before any other directives.

```
location = /ping {
  try_files DUMMY @return200;
}
location @return200 {
  return 200 'OK';
}
```